# Merge multiple files css into a one file by classes with gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-task

## Combine CSS files

Hi all, I'm working with a project in react and I use sass to process styles, I have several scss files and I group them using `gulp`, I use `gulp-sass` to generate the css and `gulp-merge-css` to join them, but they concatenate, not it combines.

Here's an example

*In a file*

```
.fooClass {
  background-color: black;
}
```

*In another file*

```
.fooClass {
  color: white;
}
```

These files should go to

```
.fooClass {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

But it does not happen, only the content is combined but not combined, the result is

```
.fooClass {
  background-color: black;
 }
.fooClass {
  color: white;
 }
```

**Is there any way to do what I want?**

My **gulp-task** is:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const mergeCSS = require('gulp-merge-css')
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

const conf = require('../conf/gulp.conf');

gulp.task('styles', styles);

function styles() {
  return gulp.src(conf.path.src('**/*.scss'))
    .pipe(sass.sync({outputStyle: 'compressed'})).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Sass'))
    .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()])).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Autoprefixer'))
    .pipe(mergeCSS({ name: 'style.css' }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8', multiplePseudoMerging: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.path.tmp()))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Comment: WebCompiler with visual studio combines, can also be done with postCSS, and cleanCss for gulp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there exists a plugin to achieve this, but **I wouldn't recommend combining** anyway, because combining CSS rules can change the precedence of the rules.

---

**Example**

Imagine a scenario where you have two elements, and two classes. The HTML code is:

```html
<div class="foo">Hello</div>
<div class="foo bar">World</div>
```

and the concatenated CSS looks like this:

```css
.foo {
  background: #000;
}

.bar {
  color: #999;
}

.foo {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

The result would be both `div`s having a background color of `#000` and a text color of `#FFF`, because the definition of the text color for `.foo` comes after `.bar`.

If you combine the rules, the CSS becomes this:

```css
.foo {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.bar {
  color: #999;
}
```

This changes the meaning, as both `div`s will still have a background color of `#000`, but the second `div` will now have a text color of `#999`, as `.bar` now takes precedence over `.foo`.